# Can a self-contained .netcore app run on AIX?

Tags: .net-core, aix, self-contained

I successfully ran self-contained .net-core 3 apps on Linux, but if I am trying to run on AIX it fails:

`bash: ./CoreConsole: cannot execute binary file: Cannot run a file that does not have a valid format.`

I know AIX is unix operating system, but does anyone managed to run self-contained .net-core apps on it?

Comment: Can you run `file $(which bash)` and `file ./CoreConsole`? The results might be illuminating.

Answer (score 1):

To run executable on AIX you need few things:

1. Application which is writen for AIX (propper AIX executable format)
2. Application which is compiled for POWER processors
3. Application which use AIX libraries

If one of them is missing you have no chance. The only exceptions are shell files, but you should be aware utilities, used by shell script may have different options